# applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone

this function is called automatically when quit application..but in my application this function  cannot called automatically

Comment: In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is called instead of the applicationWillTerminate: method when the user quits an application that supports background execution. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html for more information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This method is **only** called on your `ApplicationDelegate` instance so is this where you put your code?

If you need to be notified of when your application enters background outside of the ApplicationDelegate you can register with `NSNotificationCenter`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: whatever
    selector: @selector(enteredBackground:) 
    name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
    object: nil];
```

This will work in any class, but you obviously need to create the method `enteredBackground` or whatever you call it :)

Comment: sir how we set  multitasking enabled in iphone

Comment: You do that in your application plist

Comment: but unless you disabled multitasking it will be enabled by default. You do need iOS4 though