# Detecting when 'Home' is pressed or app is resumed (Keyboard is covering View when it resumes)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikeyboard, home-button

In my iPhone app, if the user presses the Home button while the keyboard is up, then returns to the app, the keyboard is still up but my view behind is hidden behind it!

I have some code that normally would rise and lower the view as necessary, but I can't see how to call it in this situation. How can I either detect when Home has been pressed so I can lower the keyboard, or detect when the app has been resumed so that I can rise my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application delegate is sent the [applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786) message:

> You should perform any tasks relating to adjusting your user interface before this method exits

Comment: Thanks Jim. However, the issue is with one of my Views. Can this be accessed from the application delegate?

Comment: Yes, in several different ways.  The first idea that springs to mind is to use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification.  Your view would register to listen for that notification in `viewDidLoad` and unregister in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Excellent its works. Erm, i achieved this through a combination of two peoples answers! Is it simply up to me to decide which single person deserves the green tick? i presume i cant give it to both people?

Answer (score 1):

you can check with some notification and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872099/applicationdidenterbackground)

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. Im just trying to work out what to put in 'addObserver'. Do I somehow put my View in there?

Comment: @Andy Please try like this addObserver:self