# dumping data to file when app quits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What do you all recommend as the best location in an iphone project to dump data collected from the user to a local file? Would you say that applicationWillTerminate is a good option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option on iOS 4.x is `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Indeed, according to Apple docs, an application in the background can be terminated at any time due to low memory conditions. Therefore, the suggestion is making persistent any state information at the moment the app enters background.

An excerpt from the [UIApplicationDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> You should use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. You should also disable updates to your application’s user interface and avoid using some types of shared system resources (such as the user’s contacts database). It is also imperative that you avoid using OpenGL ES in the background.
>
> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time...

Comment: If you can, it's always better to save as you go - as sergio mentions above you only have 5 seconds to perform any tasks in applicationDidEnterBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Also from Apple Docs for applicationWillTerminate:

> For applications that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user quits the application. For applications that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the application because the application simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the application is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

Therefore if you specifically request to not support backgrounding for your app or you link against iOS 3.x you should consider persisting in both places (applicationWillTerminate and applicationWillEnterBackground) to catch situations as well.

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks! One more quick question (just dont want to start a new thread) - I am trying to dump to a file an array that I have in my view controller, but its not global. How can I pass it to the app delegate? I read in a few places here about passing objects, but none were similar to this case. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to pass it to your app delegate? It sounds like you may benefit from refactoring your code and possibly creating a class that deals with your data persistance. If you really want to use your app delegate (which I would avoid) you can get a reference to it with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` then just call your persistance method and pass in your array?

Comment: I prefer to avoid using the app delegate too, but eventually, I will need to, since only in the app delegate I can know when the app is terminated, no? do you think it's better then to create a class that deals with all the data storage, but then, when will I dump it to a file? Thanks!!

Comment: It depends entirely on the design on your app and how you store/pass data around. You can register to receive the different notifications in any class see this post for how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872099/applicationdidenterbackground